# Scroll to selected row in DataTables jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a dataTable with infinite scrolling. I want to scroll to a selected row on table refresh

```
$('#table1').dataTable({
    'aaData': data,
    'aoColumns': columns,
    'bInfiniteScroll': true,
    'bColumnCollapse': true,
    'sScrollY': '200px'
});

$('#btnScroll').click(function(){
     $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTo($('#table1 tbody tr').eq(3), 800);
});
```

But it does not scroll to the  row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use animate to scroll to your position

```
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#table1 tbody tr').eq(3).offset().top
}, 800)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9t7dv/)

Comment: Does not srcoll to the selected cell

Comment: you're using `scrollTo` or `scrollTop`?

Comment: But how can we scroll to say row 30, when the page shows only 20 rows at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the scrollTo plugin.  Have you loaded it?  You can write this without that plugin as follows:

```
var selectedRow = $('#table1 tbody tr').eq(3);
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTop(selectedRow.prop('offsetTop') - $('.dataTables_scrollBody').height()/2);
```