# Scroll to specific row in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a DataTable and I would like to scroll to a specific row given the class of the row. Each row in the table has been assigned a unique class that I would like to use for selecting the containing row. Each one of the buttons in the fiddle have a selector with the unique class.

```
fnRowCallback: function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
  $(nRow).addClass( "c" + aData[0].replace(/\W/g, '') + aData[1].replace(/\W/g, '') + aData[2].replace(/\W/g, '') + aData[3].replace(/\W/g, '') );
},
```

So I would like when button1 is pressed the corresponding row of the table to come into view (for all buttons).

```
$("#button1").click( function() {
    var selection = $( "#example .cGloriaLittleSystemsAdministratorNewYork59" );
    ...
} );
```

Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/myojo7pw/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to selected row in DataTables jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731204/scroll-to-selected-row-in-datatables-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [scrollTo jQuery plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) which lets you to scroll to any element using class, id, type or a combination. Since the scrollable part of the table has `dataTables_scrollBody` class, you can activate scrollTo like this in your click events for buttons like this:

```
$("#button1").click( function() {
    var selection = $( "#example .cGloriaLittleSystemsAdministratorNewYork59" );

    $(".dataTables_scrollBody").scrollTo(selection);

    // to remove .selectedRow from existing rows
    $("tr[role='row']").removeClass("selectedRow");
    // to add .selectedRow to the navigated row
    selection.addClass("selectedRow");

} );
```

[**Demo in JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bLgsbv3b/6/)

Comment: What if datatable has paging? Any recommendation?

Comment: @DiegoPonciano : if there's paging, you can use `row().show()` - see https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/row().show()