# Datatables vertically scroll to particular row id

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables to show data. In my datatables there are some rows which are doubleclick to edit and reload the datatables after success. The problem is when the datatable reloads it goes back to the top of the table but i need to stay at the same row which i was added.

my datatable structure is like this

```
<table class='table-product' >
       <tr id='101'>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
    <tr id='102'>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
    <tr id='103'>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
    <tr id='104'>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
    <tr id='105'>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

This is JS function i am using

```
 var table2 = $('.table-product').DataTable({
    searching:true,
    processing: true,
    "language": {
    processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" style="color:#13436c;"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '},
    colReorder: {
      realtime: false
    },
    ordering: false,
    // "aaSorting": [[2,5,14,24]],
    retrieve: true,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY : '90vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,

    serverSide: true,
    fixedHeader: false,
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    "columnDefs": [],
    pageLength: {{50}},
    lengthMenu: [ 50, 100, 150, 200],
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'colvis',
        columns: ':not(.noVis)',
      }
      // {
      //   extend: 'excelHtml5',
      //   text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" style="font-size:22px;" title="Export Excel"></i>',
      //   exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export',columns: ':visible' },
      //   title: null,
      // }
    ],
    ajax: {
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#loader_modal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
          });
        $("#loader_modal").data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = 'static';
        $("#loader_modal").modal('show');
      },
      url:"{!! route('some-url') !!}",
      data: function(data) { data.default_supplier = $('.default_supplier option:selected').val(), data.prod_type = $('.prod_type option:selected').val(),
          data.prod_category = $('.prod_category option:selected').val(),
          data.prod_category_primary = $('.prod_category_primary option:selected').val(),
          data.filter = $('.filter-dropdown option:selected').val(),
          data.sortbyparam = column_name, 
          data.sortbyvalue = order },
      method: "post",
    },
      columns: [
        { data: 'checkbox', name: 'checkbox'{{@$hide_pricing_columns}} },
         ......
        { data: 'last_price_history', name: 'last_price_history' },

        // Dynamic columns start
        
      ],
      initComplete: function () {
        // Enable THEAD scroll bars
        $('.dataTables_scrollHead').css('overflow', 'auto');
        $('.dataTables_scrollHead').on('scroll', function () {
          $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
        });
      },
      drawCallback: function(){
        $('#loader_modal').modal('hide');
      },
    });
```

I have a ID on each row and i want to stay at the same row where I was working. Either i can lock the scroll here or go back to the same row after reloading of datatable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to specific row in DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468228/scroll-to-specific-row-in-datatable)

Comment: i tried this answer but i got the error that scrollto is not a function

Comment: Alternatively, you can take a look at [`row().scrollTo()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().scrollTo()), which requires you to add the [scroller extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/). Does that help?